# problems in filter in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problems in my filter , i explain you, when my program start , i initiaze the table(ng repeat)

but 
first

in console log () When I initialize the first time it puts me  "item undifined" and then it returns in directly in the filter "myfilter" and it shows me the object,

i don't uderstand why i have "items undifined"

And I would like it to do it all at once and the second problem is to link to the first problem, when I press a datepicker field it makes me 2 alert so it calls twice the filter

this is my filter code

```
   routeAppControllers.filter("myfilter", function($filter) {

    return function(items, from, to) {

        const testFrom = Date.parse(from);
        const testTo = Date.parse(to);


        if (!testFrom){
           // console.log('Not valid');
            from = moment();
        }


        if (!testTo){
            to = moment('2500-01-01');
        }



        const valids = items.reduce((acc,val) => {
                var st = val.DATE_AGENDA;
               // alert(val.DATE_AGENDA);
/*
        var res = st.substring(0, 10);
        var res = res.split("-");

        var res1= res[2]+'-'+res[1]+'-'+res[0];
        alert(res);
        var dt = new Date(res1);

*/
        const date = moment(val.DATE_AGENDA);
        if(date.isSameOrAfter(from) && date.isSameOrBefore(to))
            acc.push(val)
        return acc;
    },[]);



        return valids;
    };
});
```

this is my 2 inputs

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Date debut" class="form-control" ng-click="open1()" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="startDate" show-button-bar="false" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-change="filter()" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                        </span>

<input type="text" placeholder="Date fin" class="form-control" ng-click="open2()" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="endDate" show-button-bar="false" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-change="filter()" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                        </span>
```

and this is my ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (myData | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse | myfilter: startDate: endDate) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
```

and i make i plunker for more help

http://plnkr.co/edit/6RuUjkON4HaXE3EHg7bn?p=preview

if somenone can help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Your plunker code has no resemblance to code in question

Comment: Sorry i forgot save :( its good now http://plnkr.co/edit/6RuUjkON4HaXE3EHg7bn?p=preview

Comment: Your plunkr contains too much unnecessary code. Please, trim it down to minimal code. This way, there will be a lot of people willing to help you